# Create different MSIX installers using a flag parameter on a .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui, msix, maui-blazor, appxmanifest, maui-windows

I want to automatically create different MSIX packages/installers for the same MAUI app, so that each one runs a specific code snippet according to a flag parameter.
The user does not have to interact with the app. An installer per flag value has to be created, an once the app is installed and the user double clicks the app icon, the specific piece of code has to be run.

So far, I've tried without success the [following approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/install-parameters), trying to create a script that passes the possible values of the flag as installation parameters using the app installer and a protocol, and then trying to publish the different packages in a local path.

I would like to know whether that's feasible or there may be any other approach to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this comment about [.NET MAUI Windows target publishing/archiving](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4329).

In the article, the right way to set the MSIX is that you had to [create a self-signed certificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing) and then You could add a couple of extra parameters to also add the sign the MSIX and then trust that cert manually.